# iOS UI Test Error when tap second text field

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield, xcode-ui-testing

I am working in UI Test iOS using. My test is to type 2 text fields firstName and lastName. This test is work in simulator iphone 6 and 7, but failed when I tried in simulator iphone 5 and SE. The error is in "txtFieldLastName.tap()" code which is when tapping the second text field. I have tried to disable Connect Hardware Keyboard of simulator but still failed. How to fix that? I am confused because in simulator iOS 6 or larger it's work.

```
let txtFieldFirstName = app.textFields["firstName"]
let txtFieldLastName = app.textFields["lastName"]

txtFieldFirstName.tap()
txtFieldFirstName.typeText("First")            
txtFieldLastName.tap()
txtFieldLastName.typeText("Last")
```

Comment: Could you provide the error message?

Comment: there is no error message. i have answer the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is try to dismiss keyboard before tap the second text field. thank you.